# Saving state of UI in a C# program

Tags: c#, .net

How can I monitor for when a member of a collection (interface: `System.Collections.ICollection`) changes? I'm trying to save the order of columns in a `System.Windows.Forms.ListView.Columns`.

I've created a delegate for `public event ColumnReorderedEventHandler ColumnReordered;`

```
this.MyListView.ColumnReordered += new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnReorderedEventHandler(ColumnReordered);
```

And when my class gets called:

```
public void ColumnReordered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection chc = sender as ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection;
    ColumnReorderedEvemtArgs crea = e as ColumnReorderedEventArgs;
    if ((chc == null) || (crea == null)) return;

    // Prints expected values.
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", crea.OldDisplayIndex, crea.NewDisplayIndex);

    // Prints previous state; NOT current state.
    for (int k = 0; k < chc.Count; k++)
    {
        ColumnHeader columnHeader = chc[k] as ColumnHeader;
        if (columnHeader == null)
            break;

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", columnHeader.DisplayIndex);
    }
}
```

This leads me to believe that this is NOT where I want to save state as the changes aren't yet reflected in the object returned (`sender`). How can I save the ordering of the columns immediately as the user manipulates them?

Comment: This is because there is possibility to cancel reordering - see `Cancel` property of [ColumnReorderedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnreorderedeventargs.aspx). If all attached handlers return false in Cancel, proposed change will be executed.

Comment: What is the purpose of saving the column order? A history so they can "undo" column ordering? Different logic needs to execute if in a certain order?

Comment: @Jay, I want to save ordering between uses for a user. Also, each user may have their own preferred display arrangement.

Comment: Thanks, @NikolaMarkovinović, now how do I hook in and get notified of the change?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and some testing. The column part of the list view is a separate window handle named *SysHeader32*.

When the order of the columns changes, the header handle receives a HDM_SETORDERARRAY message:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775369(v=vs.85).aspx

In which *lParam* contains a pointer to an array which holds the modified order of the columns. For example, when you have three columns, the array would like this when nothing was changed:

```
int[] indexes = { 0, 1, 2 };
```

When I switch the first two columns, the array looks like this:

```
int[] indexes = { 1, 0, 2 };
```

You could then iterate trough the array to retrieve the columns from your list view control, using the indexes stored in the array.

So, in other words you must find the handle of the header, then setup a *WndProc* to intercept incoming windows messages, then detect if HDM_SETORDERARRAY was received. If yes, read the value of *lParam*.

You can use *EnumChildWindows* to enumurate/search trough a handle's child handles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494(v=vs.85).aspx

To setup the hook, to intercept messages for the header handle, see the following stack overflow question:

[How do I intercept messages being sent to a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843711/how-do-i-intercept-messages-being-sent-to-a-window)

Note, the HDM_SETORDERARRAY is received when the indexes are already updated.